# AWS - EC2 | installing honeypot T-pot v.20.06 installation error. Keep getting error "Debian Focal is not Supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an AWS/EC2 account and was trying to install a T-Pot Honey Pot. The following  Installation error using Debian OS in AWS/EC2 occurred:
Used the command sudo ./install.sh --typeauto --conf=tpot.conf
I keep seeing the following error using different Linux Flavors:
error "Aborting. Debian focal is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

Edit install.sh file under iso/installer/install.sh

line 21

```
myLSB_STABLE_SUPPORTED="stretch buster"
```

change it to

```
 myLSB_STABLE_SUPPORTED="stretch buster focal"
```

save and run the install again

Comment: Focal is Ubuntu 20.04  which is the recent Ubuntu version!
not sure what upgrade are you referring to!

Comment: Thank you. I was able to download the honeypot on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Awesome!, don't forget to mark the answer as verified and vote for :)